# mod_wsgi problem or?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

i have apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost 91.218.230.130:8080>
    ServerName dopisaka.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dopisalki.ru/data/www/dopisaka.ru
    SuexecUserGroup dopisalki.ru dopisalki.ru 
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/dopisaka.ru.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/dopisaka.ru.error.log
    ServerAlias www.dopisaka.ru
    ServerAdmin 911@dopisalki.ru
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    <Directory "/var/www/dopisalki.ru/data/www/dopisaka.ru">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /manager/ "/var/www/dopisalki.ru/data/www/dopisaka.ru/manager/"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/dopisalki.ru/data/www/dopisaka.ru/cgi-bin/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dopisalki.ru/data/www/dopisaka.ru/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

but http://www.dopisaka.ru/ show just a "Index of".

whats wrong?

Comment: Check your Apache error log. It it's the problem with mod_wsgi - you will see errors in that file. But I think there's something wrong with this config file. You did reload Apache with this config, didn't you? Did you get any errors in the console or in the error log file?

Comment: Apache error log was clean. but console help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included an IP address in the VirtualHost directive. Did you provide a compatible NameVirtualHost directive using that IP address along with the port? If you didn't then likely that the VirtualHost configuration isn't being used at all, and instead the default virtual host definition is being used and it is that which is set up to return the index. More often that not using an IP address in VirtualHost is not what you want to do and you should just use '*:8080', still remembering though that you need a matching NameVirtualHost directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the DocumentRoot directive. Also your wsgi script seem to be under DocumentRoot, you don't want the script under DocumentRoot because that make it readable by everyone.